# Watch is not working inside a custom attribute directive used inside another custom element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives which implement independent functionality. I am trying to use the attribute directive inside an element directive, but watch is not working on the attribute directive. Here's the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/hsyR5/8/

I want the isLoaded directive watch to be triggered whenever is-loaded attribute value is changed.

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">    
    <div ng-controller="ReportCtrl">
        <mydir is-loaded="false" id="change" expand-me="isExpanded" ng-transclude>
            <button ng-click="expandIt()"> Expand</button>
        </mydir>
    </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', [])
myApp.directive('mydir', function () {   
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            expandMe:'='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template : "<div></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('expandMe', function (){
                //load the data
                console.log('inside mydir directive');
                element[0].attributes['is-loaded'].nodeValue = ''+scope.expandMe;
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('isLoaded', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.isLoaded, function (){
                console.log('isLoaded Changed');
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('ReportCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.isExpanded = false;
  $scope.expandIt = function(){
      $scope.isExpanded = !$scope.isExpanded;
  }
})
```

Comment: why are u using element[0].attributes['is-loaded'].nodeValue whydont just your directly use http://jsfiddle.net/hsyR5/9/

Comment: yes, thanks for suggesting that. Please explain why wrapping attrs.isLoaded inside a function worked? Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `scope.$watch` if you pass a string as first argument, it needs to match a scope property.

Your attempt would be similar to writing:

```
scope.$watch("false", function (){
     ....
});
```

But `scope.false` is undefined.

Since you aren't watching a scope properrty  you can use a function that returns a variable to watch as first argument

```
scope.$watch(function (){
     return attrs.isLoaded;/* define what to watch*/
}, function(newVal,oldVal
      if(newVal !=oldVal){
           console.log('isLoaded Changed');
      }
});
```

You can also use `attrs.$observe` similar to using `$watch` on scope

In the first directive `element[0].attributes` is unnecessary since the attributes are already available as argument of `link`.
You can change an attribute using:

```
attrs.isLoaded = '' + scope.expandMe;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hsyR5/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one thing i wanted to ask. You are right that element[0].attributes is not required. But why doesn't using "element.attr('is-loaded', ''+ scope.expandMe);" work, but "attrs.isLoaded = '' + scope.expandMe;" works?

Comment: if you change something directly on element using jQuery like method...angular doesn't know, so have to call `scope.$apply()` after